# Woocommerce full size img with large - product-image.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to replace full size image with large image on woocommerce lighbox.

here is my code -

```
    <?php
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $image              = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ) );
        $image_title        = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
        $image_link         = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        $attachment_count   = count( $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids() );

        if ( $attachment_count > 0 ) {
            $gallery = '[product-gallery]';
        } else {
            $gallery = '';
        }
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="bigbox woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );

    } else {

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="Placeholder" class="bigbox" />', woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() ), $post->ID );

    }
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>
```

I've tried to change $image_link to

```
$image_link = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $image_link comes as array. to echo the image link, try,

`<?php echo $image_link[0]; ?>`
So your full code should be like [this](http://pastebin.com/KuKstsLj)

Comment: Almost there but I'm getting small thumbnail. Any idea how to get large picture?

Comment: If the original code has a filter, you don't repeat the code again.

Comment: I solved problem with this Sahriar Saikat tip and this code:
$image_link  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'shop_single' );

Comment: Yes, but mine is less code and is the correct way of doing it with the filter, and it will work when WooCommerce upgrades to 2.7. That is it won't cause an error, get_gallery_attachment_ids() is deprecated in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce has the filter **'woocommerce_single_product_image_html'** , you don't repeat the code in your theme for this.

You would add the following in your functions.php or your functions plugin.

Note: this works in 2.6x and will not work with 2.7 since they changed the single image display a lot.

```
function yourprefix_woocommerce_single_product_image_html( $html, $post_id ) {

    if ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) return; 
    //bail if WooCommerce is not installed and active since we are using the WC_VERSION constant

    if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '2.7', '<' ) ) {

        $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
        $image_link = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' ); //this is where and use the [0] on this variable in the sprintf    
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'shop_single', array( 'title' => $image_title ) );
        $html = sprintf('<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s">%s</a>', $image_link[0], $image_title, $image  );

    } //end version compare still return the html so we don't get an error

    return $html;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', 'yourprefix_woocommerce_single_product_image_html', 10, 2 );
```

Note: wp_get_attachment_image_src() is not what is used in the default code, it's wp_get_attachment_image_url() which gets the image uploaded, not a sized image. If you want the generated image use $variable = wp_get_attachment_image_src( ... ); and then $variable[0] for the url, $variable[1] width, $variable[2] height. There are plenty of tuts on this, so I won't repeat

Comment: I agree with your last comment in Sahria answer… So I up voted this answer.

Comment: Thanks. It's odd when people ignore the filters and create more code that is less maintainable.

Comment: I can agree with you . There is no reason to repeat filter but your code gave me a blank page.

Comment: @GeorgePennet I have tested this code and it's working perfectly… I think that you have some more custom code that is interfering on your function.php, so may be that's why you get a blank page.

Comment: Yes, I test all code before I share. I also have debug on in wp-config.php, there is no errors.